# Bijection between homomorphisms $\mathbb Z[i]\to R$ and set $x\in R$ with $x^2+1=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Show that there is a bijection between
>   the set $L$ of ringhomomorphisms $\mathbb Z[i]\to R$ and the set $X$
>   of $x\in R$ with $x^2+1=0$.

I can show that $\phi\colon L\to X\colon f\mapsto f(i)$ is a well-defined ring homomorphism. Now I would either like to show directly that it is bijective, or I should show that its inverse exists;
$$\phi^{-1}\colon X\to L\colon x\mapsto f:f(i)=x.
$$
Now here I am a bit stuck, because I can't really make any progress either way. I also haven't used that $R$ is commutative, it seems. Could anyone give a hint on how to continue from this point?

Btw: My course has just started dealing with rings and fields, so I barely know any theorem, except the isomorphism theorems. So I am looking for an elementary proof, if possible, at this point in my course.

Comment: Nice job finding that map. In the linked question, the solution describes the inverse map. You can just check they are mutually inverse to show it's a bijection.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't know how to show that $\phi$ is surjective. Consider $x\in X$. Then we must find $f\in L$, such that $f(i)=x$. How can I show its existence?

Comment: The solution at the duplicate explains exactly that. If $x\in R$ satisfies $x^2+1$, then there exists a ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z[X]\to R$, and consequently a ring homomorphism $\hat{f}:\mathbb Z[i]\to R$ such that $\hat{f}(i)=x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was a bit intimidated when I read "fundamental theorem of homomorphsisms for rings", so I thought it would be too advanced. But that was stupid, because we've actually had that theorem, and the proof was easy to follow. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped.